# Output database information in my html content

Tags: php, html, authentication

Im trying to display a "welcome, {first name}" to my website, but im not sure how to pull that info from my database to my page, i have looked at multiple other questions like this but i dont really follow what they want the people to do.

Here is some example code i have in a div on my html page, i want to draw their name if signed in, and nothing if they arent signed in.  I was using this code to see if i could get the name to appear in the div as just to figure out how it works but im stuck.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        echo "<p>You're logged in!</p>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<p>You're logged out!</p>";
    }
?>
```

thanks for any help :)

Comment: well first you need to connect to a database

Comment: There is multiple unclear information in your question. Did you successfully validate user's login? where is `userId` in SESSION from? Please update your question to add the part where you validate login detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the user is already authenticated, and you know the user ID,

```
<?php if($_SESSION['auth']) { << condition >> } ?>
```

you might wanna create a connection to your database and make query to extract the name,

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database); 
$query = 'SELECT username FROM tablename WHERE user_id = '.$user_id;
$username = $conn->query($query);
```

and display it.

```
<? $username; ?>
```

else, display whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Question is totally confusing ! You have said you are trying to pull data from dataBase but again in the code you are trying something from SESSION.

Make sure what you are doing is logically clear to you.

If you want to show user name then SESION will not help you. Also make sure user logged in and you have started session. If you are getting user data from database then you don't need session. Just check current user and then run query.

But all this is Php and MySQL related task not html.